# Winform reopening if an Exception is thrown

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, exception

I have a WinForm which is calling a method, using .Net Remoting, on the server.
The method is querying the database. Pretty straight forward so far. The problem is that if I close the form while this method is being executed an exception is thrown Complaining that it is expecting an `SqlParameter`, which reopens the form. I don't want the form to be reopened.

I don't want to simply suppress any `SqlException` which is thrown, because I want to be notified if an exception is thrown.

Is there a simple way around this ?

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Append("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ")
  .Append(table)
  .Append(" WHERE ")
  .Append(fieldName)
  .Append(" = @Value AND SoftDelete = 0");

SqlCommand cmd = this.m_SqlDBConnPool.GetSqlCommand(sb.ToString());
int count = -1;

lock (cmd)
{
    cmd.Parameters.Clear();
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("Value", value));
    this.m_SqlDBConnPool.ExecQuery(cmd, new SqlDBConnPool.DataReader<object>(
        delegate(SqlDataReader reader, object o)
        {
            count = reader.GetInt32(0);
            return true;
        }), null);
}
```

Please note that `SqlDBConnPool` is a class we wrote.

Comment: please show some code, the way you call the stored procedure with the parameters as well.

Comment: Why in the world would you think you need to lock a local variable?

Comment: Because this.m_SqlDBConnPool.GetSqlCommand(sb.ToString()); recycles SqlCommands. We don't want the command to be updated from another thread while it is being executed

Comment: @Jonny It comes down to how your `SqlDBConnPool` deals with being disposed (i.e. does it implement IDisposable?).

Comment: The only way you could close your form while this runs is when the posted code runs on a thread.  Never allow a thread to keep running when the UI is gone, make sure it terminated first.  Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put the following around your code...

```
try
{
    //Your code
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    //Close the form by your self
    //Send back the error
}
```

Comment: The problem with that is that I would still have to throw the exception since if an error occurs I want the client to know that an error occurred. What I don't want is that if the exception is thrown when the form was closed, the form doesn't reopen.

Comment: Add the try catch in the Form code so it can swallow or handle the exception instead of coming to the foreground.

Comment: I might be stupid but not that much. I am using a try catch block on in the form code which opens a dialogue showing the user that there was an error. That's why I asked the question to get some ideas.

Comment: Is it possible to say something like Form.Close() Before you give back the error? This should happen in the catch block.